# Nginx serving server and static build

Tags: nginx

I have one next.js server that is running on port 3000 and I have static build (created with create-react-app), that should be admin panel. So it looks like this

```
  server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/city-am-club/admin/build/;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

 location /admin/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/myproject/admin/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        default_type "text/html";
    }
location / {        
        rewrite /(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

}

I understand that location should be like this with admni panel, cause location is path after root path.

```
location / {        
        root /usr/share/nginx/myproject/admin/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        default_type "text/html";
}
```

Any way, I don't really know how to configure this correct. Right now I cannot get my built files, i tried a lot of different variations of this config. ATM I have a behavior when all my routes `location /`, even when I try to react `/admin` it shows me 404 page (custom page of `locations /` server template).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your NGINX config.

```
 server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/city-am-club/admin/build/;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {        
        rewrite /(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        location /admin/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/myproject/admin/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        default_type "text/html";
        }

}
```

If the admin path is not `/usr/share/nginx/myproject/admin/build` then change the alias section.