# How can I setup an admin panel for my Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, react-admin

I'm developing a Next.js app and need an admin panel to manage data, users and posts. I'm thinking it would be better to setup the panel as a separate app instead of a new path in the current app.

I've looked at react-admin but it is regular React.js.

I saw these posts about setting up Next.js with a separate react-admin app but I don't know as much about nginx.

[Nginx reverse proxy to both nextjs and react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603297/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-both-nextjs-and-react-admin)

[Nginx serving server and static build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741038/nginx-serving-server-and-static-build)

Any suggestions if you've setup an admin panel for Next.js before?

Comment: I've implemented my admin panel on am `/admin` route (in the same app). But I'm strongly considering moving it to a separate app on a subdomain. My whole app is SSG and my admin panel is CSR (client side rendered). This is sometimes hard to deal with. Have you implemented it yet?